# onblur is firing before the value is changed

Tags: javascript, html

I have two inputs that are part of a `<form>`. I'm trying to get the value of the input once one of them is changed (dpFin). The problem is that that inside the event when I get the value using `var endDt = document.getElementById("dpFin").value;` I'm getting not the new value, but the old value. How I can get the newly set values instead?

```js
function compararFechas() {
  var startDt = document.getElementById("dpInicio").value;
  var endDt = document.getElementById("dpFin").value;

  console.log(startDt);
  console.log(endDt);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <label>Inicio:</label>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="dpInicio" name="dpInicio" class="form-control datepicker-here" data-language='es' data-timepicker="true" data-time-format='hh:ii aa' readonly />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <label>Fin:</label>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="dpFin" name="dpFin" class="form-control datepicker-here" data-language='es' data-timepicker="true" data-time-format='hh:ii aa' readonly onblur="compararFechas()" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: because when you focus on that date picker the input is blurred. I would assume the date picker has custom events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a 3rd party datepicker by the looks of it, so your `blur` event never gets triggered. There will likely be an event on your datepicker you can hook into if you check the documentation.

`blur` will trigger when you lose `focus` on the `input`. When using a datepicker you've already lost `focus` when the datepicker pops up - hence the old value.

Answer (score 0):

*blur* event will trigger when you are no longer focused on that control, therefor if you want see the change immediately, you should use or **oninput** event instead. But as @Sean T mentioned, it must be an event in your 3rd party datepicker to trigger what you want.

I hope it helps :)